# Proof that margin percentage is equal to the sub margin percentages

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have the following input:
`c` for cost, `r` for revenue, `m` for margin and `mp` for margin percentage,
where: $m = r - c$ and $mp = (r - c) / r$.

Now let $c_1, c_2, ..., c_n$ where $c = \sum_{n=1}^{n} {c_i}$ are subcosts

let $r_1, r_2, ..., r_n$ where $r = \sum_{n=1}^{n} {r_i}$ are subrevenues

$mp_i = (r_i - c_i) / r_i$

Now I wanna prove mathmatically that
$mp_i = mp$

I am not sure though if the statement is right that is why I wanna prove it or negate it.

I started with:

$ mp = (r - c) / r = (\sum_{n=1}^{n} {r_i} - \sum_{n=1}^{n} {c_i} ) /  
 \sum_{n=1}^{n} {r_i}$

$ mp = (r_1 + r_2 ... + r_n ) - (c_1 + c_2 + ... + c_n) / (r_1 + r_2 ... + r_n )$

$ mp = (r_1 - c_1) + (r_2 - c_2) + ... + (r_n - c_n) / (r_1 + r_2 ... + r_n )$

$ mp = m_1 + m_2 + ... + m_n / (r_1 + r_2 ... + r_n )$

$ mp = m_1 + m_2 + ... + m_n / r $

But I couldn't get anywhere!, Also I tried to prove that $mp / mp_i$ is equal to `1` and no luck.

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: @Saad
Thank you. I added what I've tried